# Error when call azure.createQueueService()

Tags: node.js, azure

I am testing some code about node and azure. According the code snippet @ https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node

```
var queueService = azure.createQueueService(); 
queueService.createQueueIfNotExists('taskqueue', function(error){

if(!error){
    // Queue exists
}

});
```

---

In my code I tried:-

```
var AZURE = require('azure');

function TestQueue(QueueName)
{
    var queueService = AZURE.createQueueService(); // error occurred at this line 
    queueService.createQueueIfNotExists(QueueName, function(error){
        if(!error)
        {
            console.log("ok");
            RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "ok", Status: "ok" });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error: "+error);
            RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "error", Status: "error" });
        }
    });
}
```

Error message:-

NoMatchError: The provided settings {"blobendpoint":"https://undefined.blob.core.windows.net","tableendpoint":"https://undefined.table.core.windows.net","queueendpoint":"https://undefined.queue.core.windows.net"}
 are not complete.

Question is how to create
queueService?

By the way, following code
work fine. But it is not enough for me. I need queue service also.

```
var AZURE = require('azure');
var SERVICEB_BUS_SERVICE = AZURE.createServiceBusService();

function createQueue(queueName)
{
        SERVICEB_BUS_SERVICE.createQueueIfNotExists(queueName,  function(error){
            if(!error){
                console.log('%s queue created or exist: ',queueName );
                RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "ok", Status: "ok" })
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('%s queue creation error.',queuename );
                RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "error", Status: "error" })
            }
        })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're getting this error is because no account name/key is specified. Try something like this:

```
var AZURE = require('azure');
TestQueue('testqueue1');
function TestQueue(QueueName)
{
    var queueService = AZURE.createQueueService('accountname', 'accountkey'); // error occurred at this line 
    queueService.createQueueIfNotExists(QueueName, function(error){
        if(!error)
        {
            console.log("ok");

        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error: "+error);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the previous error. But got a new Error: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:f0cb9b35-e540-41e9-87ae-1311c5e320b0
Time:2014-02-13T12:19:41.6685088Z. I'm calling this method form a custom api configured as can call only authenticated user only. I do authenticate before I call. I'm not sue about parameter 'accountname', 'accountkey'. I just tried accountname="servicebus name" accountkey="DEFAULT KEY". Can you tell me what should it be?

Comment: You have to get storage account name and key from Windows Azure Portal portal. This queue is different than service bus queues. You may find this link useful for comparison between the two: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx.

Comment: Wow confusing name. Actually I came into this while trying to follow this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/ here it mentioned var queueService = azure.createQueueService(); As u can see code to create service bus queue and ran into error when tried to crate queueService.

Comment: Can't blame you :). The example talks about storage queues. So the question is - do you want to create storage queue or service bus queue? Code sample in my answer would create a storage queue while the 2nd code sample in your question would be for service bus queue.

Comment: I need service bus queue. I need this call to work var queueService = azure.createQueueService(); So that I can use queueService.peekMessages()

Comment: But this message is for storage queues. I don't think you can use this on a service bus queue. Service bus related stuff can be found here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus.

Comment: Well, form MSDN link http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/ it says to use this. I found many conflicting and miss guiding stuff in MSDN earlier. So you might be right. Could you tell me how do I call queueService.peekMessages() note this is service bus queue. To get a message from service bus queue without removing message from queue.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with service bus. I would actually recommend that either you post a new question all together with this specific problem or edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I got to learn there 2 different queue in azure :D