# how to call azure service bus queue queueService.peekMessages()?

Tags: node.js, azure, message-queue

I tried to follow this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/

My code:-

```
var AZURE = require('azure');

function TestQueue(QueueName)
{
    var queueService = AZURE.createQueueService(); // error occurred at this line 
    queueService.createQueueIfNotExists(QueueName, function(error){
        if(!error)
        {
            console.log("ok");
            RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "ok", Status: "ok" });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error: "+error);
            RESPONSE.send(200, { Message: "error", Status: "error" });
        }
    });
}
```

Error message:-

Error message:-

NoMatchError: The provided settings {"blobendpoint":"https://undefined.blob.core.windows.net","tableendpoint":"https://undefined.table.core.windows.net","queueendpoint":"https://undefined.queue.core.windows.net"} are not complete.

Note that there are azure storage queue and azure service bus queue. I need service bus queue. So that I could call queueService.peekMessages(). My goal is to get a queue message without deleting the message from queue.

I ask same question in another thread @ [Error when call azure.createQueueService()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726388/error-when-call-azure-createqueueservice/21728838?iemail=1&noredirect=1#21728838) it was mixed up with 2 different queue stuff. Eventually I didn't get my answer. Wish to get a answer this time. Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 0):

```
var azure = require('azure');

var namespace = 'YOUR-NAMESPACE-GOES-HERE';
var key = 'YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE';
var issuer = 'owner'
var acs = namespace + '-sb';
var host = namespace + '.servicebus.windows.net';
var authProv = null;
var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(namespace, key, issuer, acs, host, authProv);
var queueName = 'nodequeue';

console.log('Connecting...');
serviceBusService.createQueueIfNotExists(queueName, function(error){

  if(error){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected, receiving...');

  serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(queueName,  { isPeekLock: true },function(error, msg){

    if(error){
      console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Received:');
    console.dir(msg);

  });

});
```

source: https://gist.github.com/hectorcorrea/7372111

Comment: besides that, you can find more info in here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/

Comment: Thanks Thiago! But it returns all details in json form. I just want to get a message as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781243/how-to-call-azure-service-bus-queue-queueservice-peekmessages/21786167?iemail=1&noredirect=1#21786167 queueService.peekMessages(queueName, function(error, messages){
    if(!error){
        // Messages peeked
        // Text is available in messages[0].messagetext
    }
});